# GCC: Statically adding an external shared-object to the compilation

Tags: gcc, linkage

I have 2 C libraries:

1. A dependency library, compiled as a shared-object
2. My library - which I also want to compile as a shared-object

I want to compile my library into a shared object, but I do **not** want the dependency library to be loaded on runtime.

I.e. I want the dependency library to become a part of the shared-object I create from my library, so one won't have to add the dependency to LD_LIBRARY_PATH when using my library.

How can I do it with GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a XY problem: You want to add a SO statically *to avoid using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`*. Allow me to address the latter and ignore the former. ;-)

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a means to *temporarily overwrite* the library search path. Note "overwrite": The paths given in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are searched *first*, and if a library is found in them, the standard search paths are *not* considered for that library. It "knocks out" other versions that might be installed in the standard paths. It's easy to see how this could have surprising and unwanted consequences. It is a *debug* feature, mostly, so you are right in not wanting to use it.

There are three "correct" ways to address this:

1) **Install** the dependency in one of the standard search paths (`/usr/lib/*` / `/lib/*`, check `/etc/ld.so.conf` for a list). This will require superuser priviledges.

2) **Add** the path of the dependency to the standard search paths (in `/etc/ld.so.conf`). This will require superuser priviledges.

3) **Configure** the path of the dependency into your library at compilation time (`-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib/`). This will add the given path to the paths searched *by this library only*. It does *not* require any special priviledges, and has none of the disadvantages that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has.

As an aside, you can check where your binary does "find" its libraries via `ldd <filename>`.

Comment: Good advice.  I wanted to add a link to http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html since I think that it is a very good read for anyone trying to understand why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be used as a debugging tool ONLY.